# Thumbnails does not display in media library for a multisite setup

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am using wordpress 4.3.1, and thumbnails does not display in media library of subsite, rest all images works perfectly fine even in mainsite. Media library also works fine in main library. Even grid layout does not work and just keeps loading infinitely. I searched everywhere and wasted a whole day and still not able to arrive at a solution :( my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to reinstall the the whole Multisite Network because my main domain had already a subdmoain in it.

If you main domain is like:

```
http://www.example.com
```

You will need to reinstall the network with main domain as:

```
http://example.com
```

I did that and the pictures are shown again.